# How do I change the table background color without overriding the cell background colour

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create this type of table for my coding lessons:

[https://www.google.com/search?q=html+table&sxsrf=ALiCzsYTjrfZjTOHXsYbF2DALFnJdSEATA:1651764097001&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQoITi1Mj3AhWDiFwKHZYwDq4Q_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1920&bih=937&dpr=1#imgrc=kgeZ4ZBeec_jdM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HX8cq.png)

But I can't change the background colour of the table without it affecting the colour of the cell

Here is my code:

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<title> Info </title>
<style> 
table ,th, td, caption {
border: 1px Solid Red;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 30px;
}
</style>
<body>
    
    <table style="font-familt: Calibri; background-color: #2ECC71;
```

width = 50%">

```
    <tr bgcolor = #ffffff;>
    
    <th> Days </th> <th background-color = white;> Weather </th>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr bgcolor = #ffffff;>
    
    <td> Monday </td> <td> Sunny </td>
    
    </tr>
    
    <tr bgcolor = #ffffff;>
    
    <td> Tuesday </td> <td> Rainy </td> 
    
    </tr>
    
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please can someone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

"Table" is the full table
"TH" are the headers
"TD" are the cells

Best practice to stick to one standard with where you put your styles.
Either put them in the style tag at the top (page level) or put them all in your html elements (inline), consistency is best early on, but here is the JSfiddle doing what you need:

https://jsfiddle.net/dmiranda9872/bx1ste92/15/

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
  <title> Info </title>
  <style> 

    table ,th, td, caption {
    }
    table {
        border-spacing: 30px; 
        background-color: #2ECC71;
        width: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 5px;
    }
    th, td {
      background-color: white;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th> Days </th> 
          <th> Weather </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Monday </td> 
          <td> Sunny </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td> Tuesday </td> 
          <td> Rainy </td> 
         </tr>
      </table>
  </body>
</html>
```